# vscode regex replace field

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

In my vscode, I try to use regex to replace some words. But the replace field of vscode in its search leftbar doesn't want to read regex and instead takes it as a common string. What am I doing wrong?

[image: img]

Comment: You're not using any capture groups so _I think_ you'll literally replace what you find with `$1`... is that intentional?

Comment: Also are you sure you want to use `[A-z]`? What are you actually trying to capture? `[A-z]` != `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Try `([A-Za-z]{3,20})Field::` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: James, I'm sure about [A-z]. That's what I need. And no, it was not intentional.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wiktor Stribizew in the comments answered. I thought regexp  already reads it [A-z]{3,20} as capture group.

Comment: You should not post others' solutions as answers.